# Is there a way to detect when all child items within a QTreeWidgetItem have been marked 'hidden'?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

Is there a preferred way to detect when all of a `QTreeWidgetItem`'s children are marked as hidden?  Currently, I'm iterating over all of them every time any of them are hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a counter of hidden items and change the value of the counter if an item changed its state of hidden-ness. So each time you use the information you do not iterate over all items!

Comment: I don't know if this solved my problem, but it sounds reasonable!